# How would you link a linked list with different struct

Tags: c, linked-list

I have 2 different stuct

```
    typedef struct name {

    char*markerName;
    struct test *next;

}name_t;

 typedef struct test {

    int grade;
    int studentNumber;
    struct test *next;


}test_t;
```

and this function

```
void test(name_t* marker1,int data)
{
        test_t *temp= malloc(sizeof(test_t));
        test_t *location=NULL;
        temp->grade=data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        location=marker1->next;
        if(location==NULL)
        {
        //  printf("%i \n",temp->grade);
            marker1->next=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            while(location!=NULL)
            {
                printf("%i \n",location->grade);
                printf("%p \n",location->next);
                location=location->next;
            }
            location=temp;
        }
}
```

the problem is we are creating an array of the stuct name and creating a linked list of the test after EACH ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY. How would I link the node of the struct name into the stuct test?

I printed the next out and they keep pointing to NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a linked list can only contain one data type.  If you want to have a list containing both structure types, you can emulate this using a union:

```
struct name {
   char* markerName;
};

struct test {
   int grade;
   int studentNumber;
};

// Indicates the type of data stored in the union
enum dtype { NONE, NAME, TEST };

// Combination of the above structures, suitable for a mixed-type list
struct combo {
   struct combo*   next; // Next structure in the linked list
   enum dtype      type; // Indicates which of the union fields is valid
   union {
      struct name  name;
      struct test  test;
   };
};
```

This stores both sets of data in a single structure, allows you to make lists from the structures, and enables you to keep track of which type of data is currently valid.

Comment: so there is no possible way to start a linked list with a head of one type and rest of the body another type other then this method?

Comment: oh thanks , the Union helps a lot. I hate when text book just give you code ( and half of it ) and assume we are all c wizard and can figure out what they are talking about. This union does the trick nicely Thanks again

Comment: @user2135885- If your list will contain exactly one `struct name` at the top of the list and all the rest are `struct test`, then the union-based approach isn't necessary.  You can have a single `struct name` that has a pointer to a list of `struct test` objects (the `name` won't be part of the list, it will just point to it).  If you want more than one of each struct type, however, then you'll need something more sophisticated (like the union).

Answer (score 1):

You are overshooting past the end of your linked list. You end up with 'NULL' for your `location` variable, which, even if it could be assigned, is still a local variable that goes out of context when your function exits. Your while loop should look more like this:

```
while(location->next != NULL)
{
    printf("%i \n",location->grade);
    printf("%p \n",location->next);
    location = location->next;
}

location->next = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a struct with two types of next pointers: one of type name_t and other of type test_t. You can use the one you want for linking and leave the other one NULL. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I was wondering how would I linked them with a linked list always starts with the name. And increase the number of the test each time as it is marked. If no test is marked it is NULL. I cant seem to link from the name to the test

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pointer to type `void`. This, of course, assumes that you know the type of the next object somehow.

When you want to create a heterogeneous data structure, it might be smarter to have only one struct type of nodes, and have two "payload" variables in the nodes, one which tells you the type of the node, and a pointer to a structure with the actual data.

Comment: how would you go about doing this? just 
void *ptr in name_t and when call it like test_t *current = (test_t*)(stuctname -> ptr)? also why didnt my method work?